# MySQL Routine Programming, mutliple tables and string operation

Tags: mysql, procedure

okay, here is a problem i ran into.. its quite difficult to explain but i will try to do my best!

i have a database with 2 tables:

1 class table

```
classname | points                     | max | min
_____________________________________________________
Land      | tree,bush,house            | 1   | 0.2
Sea       | fish,water                 | 1   | 0.3
Air       | bird,plane,moon,sun,clouds | 1   | 0.5
```

2 data table:

```
ID | classname | points
___________________________
5  | Land      |
6  | Land      |
9  | Land      |
11 | Sea       |
15 | Sea       |
20 | Air       |
1  | Land      |
```

the class table has all the possible classnames of the data table in it
if the points column has rows where points are blank they should be edited as showed in the following result...

---

now what the result should be:

data table:

```
ID | classname | points
_________________________________________________________
5  | Land      | [["tree",A],["bush",B],["house",C]]
6  | Land      | [["tree",D],["bush",E],["house",F]]
9  | Land      | [["tree",G],["bush",H],["house",I]]
11 | Sea       | [["fish",F],["water",G]]
15 | Sea       | [["fish",H],["water",I]]
20 | Air       | [["bird",J],["plane",K],["moon",L],["sun",M],["clouds",N]]
1  | Land      | [["tree",O],["bush",P],["house",Q]]
```

the letters from A-Q in points column should be random decimal numbers between min and max of the class table

would be extremely grateful if somebody could help me out with this problem, if theres any further info needed just ask!

im a beginner :S

Comment: To be honest, I stopped reading when I saw data commaseparated in one column. Never ever do that. Read about database normalization, change your DB design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but first look at the table tells me that the relationship might be wrong.
However It depends on your needs. I cannot understand the whole question but try to store the classtable ID in datatable.

Comment: changing the tables would be a pain in the... because they are used by other procedures...
my main problem is that i need a procedure which will generate the points column accordingly in the data table (input for the generation is in the class table)